# Change default path of the whole .ssh folder

Tags: server, ssh, home-directory

I have a problem with my server and for some reason (which are not important here) i'm not able to use my default home folder (`/home/$USER`). At the moment i'm setting my `$HOME` everytime i login so that when i `cd ~` the path is changed to `/newhome/$USER`.

Everything seems to work besides ssh. The problem is that ssh keep searching for `/home/$USER/.ssh` folder for the public/private key and known_host instead of using `/newhome/$USER/.ssh`:

```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Could not create directory '/home/$USER/.ssh': No such file or directory
```

I already changed the `AuthorizedKeysFile` option in sshd_config file, i can login using keys but the problem persists. How can i tell ssh that the new default home folder is `/newhome/$USER/.ssh`?

Comment: It looks like ssh-keygen uses `getpwuid` to get the user's home directory directly from the password database (as part of the `struct passwd`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to generate the ssh public/private keys in your desired directory instead of the default `/home/$USER/.ssh`. Please provide the desired path while executing `ssh-keygen -t rsa` command. If you notice, the keys have got generated in the default path instead of `/newhome/$USER/.ssh`. Also, the new path need not contain a `.ssh` hidden directory. You are free to create any directory structure you like. Only ensure that the new directory has `700` permissions.
2. Edit the property `IdentityFile` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to point to the new `id_rsa`.
3. Edit the property `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to point to the desired path.
4. Restart the ssh daemon. On my CentOS m/c, I do it as : `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for, but you can move the contents of your entire `~/.ssh` directory to some other directory, then delete `~/.ssh` and create a symbolic link to your new directory called `~/.ssh`

```
mkdir ~/alternative
mv ~/.ssh/* ~/alternative
rm -rf ~/.ssh
ln -s ~/alternative ~/.ssh
```

This integrates well with the `gnome-keyring-ssh` service which acts like a wrapper for `ssh-agent` and prompts you, with a graphical popup, for your SSH key passphrase the first time you use it whilst logged in.

If you simply use the `IdentityFile` field under a Host config in `~/.ssh/config` to point to a different directory, then `gnome-keyring-ssh` seems so have some trouble finding your SSH key and you'll be forced to enter your passsphrase into the terminal every time the key is used. I haven't figured out why, but I think `gnome-keyring-ssh` just has it built-in to only properly look at the contents of `~/.ssh`.

If anyone knows how to configure `gnome-keyring-ssh` to look at any other folder besides `~/.ssh`, please let me know.